# Run Python script file in exe from PHP under Windows 10

Tags: python, php, windows, cmd, vosk

I need to run a Python script file in exe from PHP under Windows 10, specifically it is the vosk-client.exe file, if I run the file from CMD command prompt it works perfectly but if I run it from PHP with exec(), shell_exec() or `` doesn't work and I don't get any response.

```
$com = "C:/Users/joe/AppData/Local/Programs/Python/Python311/Scripts/vosk-cli.exe -i file.wav -o file.ddt";
exec($com, $output, $retval);
echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
print_r($output);
```

I need to execute the command from PHP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I already solved it, a PHP file must be created with the exec() command and it must be called from another PHP file through php -q but placing the path where php.exe is, the file voicetext_vosk.php contains the exec() that runs the pyton .exe script for example:

```
    $com = "c:/xampp/php/php.exe -q 
    c:/xampp/htdocs/callcapture/webApp/callcapture/voicetext_vosk.php 
    c:/audio/2024/03/11/10/20240311_103400_GWKF.wav";
    $output=null;
    $retval=null;
    echo $com."<br>";
    exec($com, $output, $retval);
    echo "Returned with status $retval and output:\n";
    print_r($output);
```